# Converting "2013-09-06 10:30pm GMT+1" string to PHP DateTIme object in UTC

Tags: php, string, parsing, datetime, utc

I am trying to convert the following string: `2013-09-06 10:30pm GMT+1` to a PHP `DateTime` object. In the process, it also has to convert it to UTC. I tried the code below but obviously that was incorrect, but I don't really know where to go from here:

```
$datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('YY-MM-DD HH-IIm tzcorrection', '2013-09-06 10:30pm GMT+1', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

I know there are lot of similar topics out there. But they do not cover this format and the conversion to UTC. Because of the conversion to UTC, I believe it is not possible to use `strtotime()` for this.

Comment: Have you RTFM for the date format specifiers? Or are you just guessing them?

Comment: I have read them, just don't know how to use them properly, hater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work just fine:-

```
$date = new \DateTime('2013-09-06 10:30pm GMT+1');
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($date);
```

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/BmXRr);

See also http://php.net/date for more information on date string formats.

One issue with your date string is the 'GMT+1' part, there is no valid date string for this (hopefully somebody else can help with that), so it is difficult to make \DateTime::createFromFormat() work in this case. However the DateTime constructor seems to cope with it quite well when left to its own devices.

Comment: Wow, that was easy.. Thanks for helping me out! Yes, I tested multiple scenario's and the date time constructor does the magic.